# What extension/program should I use if I want to see binding errors?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, binding

I have a lot of struggle with my application, basically because I can't see the binding errors which are not shown by the output window (I'm using Visual Studio and I have my application in WPF using MVVM).I have tried to change the platform although I don't think it was the best idea,because it still didn't work.

What I can do in order to see my bindings error even if my output window doesn't catch all of them?

Comment: Are you running the Debug version of your application?

Comment: Yes,but the debug doesn't catch all the errors in the binding.There are still some that don't appear in the debug window but are there and I would like to know if there is a special program/extension that could catch those little binding errors.

Comment: `{Binding Whatever, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the verbosity level of output window (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx)):

> Tools / Options... / Debugging / Output Window / WPF Trace Settings / Data Binding

For example set it to "All" and check if this affects binding errors in output window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you,@Andrea.It works like a charm :)